# How to get DataTemplate to Recognize GenericType

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am displaying nodes in a TreeView control, and I am having issues with getting the data to display correctly with generics. More specifically, it seems that WPF is having trouble locating the data template. I'm guessing it is because the x:Type is declared to be `` NodeViewModel`1 ``, and the actual type is `NodeViewModel< INode>`. However, the XAML will not compile if I try to use `NodeViewModel< INode>`.

I've got a HierachialDataTemplate that looks like the following:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" 
        DataType="{x:Type viewModels:NodeViewModel`1}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Node.NodeDescription}" />                
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

the NodeViewModel is declared as such:

```
public class NodeViewModel<T> where T : INode
{
    public T Node { get {...} set {...} }
}
```

the nodes interface looks as such:

```
public interface INode
{
    string NodeDescription { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there what you're trying to do is supported. You could probably write a custom `MarkupExtension` to return a closed generic type, but it looks like you want to use the same `DataTemplate` for any `NodeViewModel<T> where T : INode`. In this case, WPF would need to support open generics as keys. Which it doesn't.

If that is the case, you're much better off just giving your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` a key, and applying it directly to the `TreeView`.

Or create a `DataTemplateSelector` and check the type of data item to select the proper template.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, Abe. I was afraid that was the case. This code started out much simpler; but keeps snowballing with every new requirement. I guess you could say I'm doing RAD (Requirements As-you-go Development). Thanks. I'll try as you suggested.